# upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx

I have 2 Harbor servers running below nginx server (acting as load balancer and reverse proxy), namely harbor.

load balance nginx config:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    upstream harbor {
        ip_hash;
        server 10.57.18.120;
        server 10.57.18.236;
    }

    server{
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://harbor;
        }
    }
}
```

nginx config in harbor:

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
  use epoll;
  multi_accept on;
}

http {
  tcp_nodelay on;

  # this is necessary for us to be able to disable request buffering in all cases
  proxy_http_version 1.1;


  upstream registry {
    server registry:5000;
  }

  upstream ui {
    server ui:80;
  }


  server {
    listen 80;

    # disable any limits to avoid HTTP 413 for large image uploads
    client_max_body_size 0;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://ui/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      # When setting up Harbor behind other proxy, such as an Nginx instance, remove the below line if the proxy already has similar settings.
      # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_request_buffering off;
    }

    location /v1/ {
      return 404;
    }

    location /v2/ {
      proxy_pass http://registry/v2/;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      # When setting up Harbor behind other proxy, such as an Nginx instance, remove the below line if the proxy already has similar settings.
      # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_request_buffering off;

    }

    location /service/ {
      proxy_pass http://ui/service/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      # When setting up Harbor behind other proxy, such as an Nginx instance, remove the below line if the proxy already has similar settings.
      # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_request_buffering off;
    }
  }
}
```

When both upstream servers are up, everything is ok, but if one upstream is down, nginx can't route requests to the server. Here are the logs:

```
2016/11/17 09:05:28 [error] 6#6: *1 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.57.2.138, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.57.18.236:80/", host: "10.57.18.236:2000"
2016/11/17 09:05:28 [warn] 6#6: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 10.57.2.138, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.57.18.236:80/", host: "10.57.18.236:2000"
2016/11/17 09:05:28 [error] 6#6: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.57.2.138, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.57.18.120:80/", host: "10.57.18.236:2000"
2016/11/17 09:05:28 [warn] 6#6: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 10.57.2.138, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.57.18.120:80/", host: "10.57.18.236:2000"
10.57.2.138 - - [17/Nov/2016:09:05:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36" "-"
2016/11/17 09:05:28 [error] 6#6: *1 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 10.57.2.138, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://apps/favicon.ico", host: "10.57.18.236:2000", referrer: "http://10.57.18.236:2000/"
10.57.2.138 - - [17/Nov/2016:09:05:28 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "http://10.57.18.236:2000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36" "-"
2016/11/17 09:05:34 [error] 6#6: *7 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 10.57.2.138, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://apps/", host: "10.57.18.236:2000"
10.57.2.138 - - [17/Nov/2016:09:05:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/601.6.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.1 Safari/601.6.17" "-"
```

It shows `"upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream"` and `"no live upstreams while connecting to upstream"`, when upstream1 is down, but upstream2 is still up.

But I still get the `"502 Bad Gateway"` if I use domainUrl. At this time, visiting upstream2 (via IP) in browser works fine.

I tried to add `"proxy_next_upstream"` in http, in server, in the `location /` block, same problem.

Comment: Try using least_conn or round_robin instead of ip_hash, to check if it works

Comment: @aliasav still the same problem, thanks.

Comment: please give a brief of the infrastructure that you are using. The 2 IPs you have mentioned, they must have nGinx running in them as well right. Also, the config you mentioned above is a different m/c right? Have you configured nginx rules for port 80 in the 2 upstreams? Also, how are you simulating the server down scenario?

Comment: also, are there any active ip tables rules on the upstreams?

Comment: @aliasav I updated the whole config file. and no iptables rules. All the programs is running with docker container. I stop some container to simulate the server down scenario.

Comment: I find the problem! I modified the upstream, only left server1, it's fine. but left server 2, occur 502. So, although server2 can be visited by IP directly, it must be something wrong with it.